# Models for continous dependent variables in large(wrt predictors) datasets in R

Tags: r, bigdata, linear-regression, prediction

I have a data set with 4000 variables and 10 000 rows. I would like to use lm() to predict but its taking extremely long to build a model. I don't want to use rpart because it gives me fixed values for similar observations. I would like more variability in results and lower mse. Are there other models apart from lm() that I can use or a faster way of building a lm?

Comment: What are you predicting? A single value for each row?

Comment: Yes, just a single value per row

Comment: Using 4000 predictors is not going to work (far too many relative to your number of observations, and they are almost certainly many correlated predictors). You'll need to use a method of regularized or sparse regression such as LASSO (which could be done using the glmnet package). It will still take a while to run but there's no way around that. In any case this question would be better on http://stats.stackexchange.com/, but really needs a lot more detail about what the variables and observations represent.